# How to apply validation of method param value in java using annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to achieve object-based access control using annotations. Would like to verify user's access to a specific object with minimal code.

Assume i have a spring mvc request handler:

```
public String updateForm(Form form){

    //update form
    formService.updateForm(form);

}
```

I would like to add annotation which can validate based on spring security's logged in user if the user has access.

```
@ValidateAuth
public String updateForm(Form form){

    //dont allow if no auth
    //update form
    formService.updateForm(form);

}
```

Now the annotation should consider the form's id(form.getId()) as well as logged in user principal to check if the auth is allowed. I'm trying to see if there is a way to do it via aop where we can read a argument's value as well in a neat way.

Kindly help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring security has support for that.

Comment: Hi Deinum, Spring security has support for role based validation. We can specify the roles but I didnt find how we can validate object based acces control rather than role based access control.

Comment: You seem to have missed (or haven't read) the [section on ACL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/domain-acls.html) in the reference guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hadn't seen this. You can add this as an answer and I shall upvote. Cheers. (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security has out-of-the-box support for ACL.

It is covered in [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/domain-acls.html) of the Spring Security reference guide.

When configured you can use the `@PreAuthorize` tag with [an expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations) to allow or disallow access to the method. You could also filter results from a method.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#form, 'admin')")
public String updateForm(Form form){ ... }
```

You can also make it a bit more complex

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR") and hasPermission(#form, 'admin')")
public String updateForm(Form form){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @m-deinum